# codeigniter active record select query not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, activerecord

i would like to get `industry` of a `candidate` from the `database` for that i have written the following:

```
 $candidateID = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';

 function get_industry($candidateID) {
    $this->db->select('current_industry');
    $this->db->group_by('current_industry');
    $this->db->from('candidate_details');

    $this->db->where_in('user_id', $candidateID);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    print_r($this->db->last_query());
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but when i execute this query it only returns me the industry of the `first` candidate out of `9`

i dont know what i am missing here..any help or suggestion would be a great help..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
 $candidateID = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';

function get_industry($candidateID) {
  $where = 'user_id in ('.rtrim($candidateID, ",").')';
  $this->db->select('current_industry');
  $this->db->group_by('current_industry');
  $this->db->from('candidate_details');

  $this->db->where($where);

$query = $this->db->get();
print_r($this->db->last_query());
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: sysntex error:
SELECT `current_industry` FROM (`candidate_details`) WHERE `where` user_id in (1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,) GROUP BY `current_industry`

Comment: SELECT `current_industry` FROM (`candidate_details`) WHERE `user_id` in (1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,) GROUP BY `current_industry`

Comment: you have `,` into your list

Comment: remove the last comma

Comment: $ID = "";
                    foreach ($result as $res) {
                        $ID .= $res->user_id . ',';
                    }

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the data as array in the where_in

```
$this->db->where_in('user_id', array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
```

In your case try like

```
$this->db->where_in('user_id', explode(",",$candidateID));
```

Comment: Hey u welcome and dont need to address me with sir, I am not such a big person to be address with Sir :)

Comment: that's your awesome good and true nature... but i would like to give you true respect for your given important time to my question.. so for me you are Sir... and please allow me.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing  `$this->db->where_in('user_id', $candidateID);`

You can do like this:

```
 $this->db->where_in('user_id', explode(",",$candidateID));
```